# Print the second largest number on the list

Tags: dart

I need to print the second largest number on the list, the output from the below code is all elements in the list except the first and the last one.

What is the mistake?

```dart
void main () {
List a = [9,6,4,10,13,2,3,5];
 a.sort;
 for(int x in a){
  for (int max in a){
   for (int second_last in a){
    if (x > max) {
    second_last = max;
    max = x;
    } else if (x > second_last && x != max) {
      second_last = x;
      print(second_last);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. You're not actually sorting the list.  The sort method returns a new sorted list, it doesn't sort the existing list.  So you need to do:

```dart
a = a.sort;
```

2. You're iterating over the list 3 times when you only need to iterate over it once.
3. You're not keeping track of the second largest number, you're just printing it out as you find it.
4. You're not checking for duplicates.  If there are duplicate numbers in the list, your code will print them out multiple times.

Here's a corrected pseudo-code

```dart
void main() {
  List a = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5];
  


a.sort;
  int max = a[0];
  int second_last = a[0];
  for (int x in a) {
    if (x > max) {
      second_last = max;
      max = x;
    } else if (x > second_last && x != max) {
      second_last = x;
    }
  }
  print(second_last);
}
```

Comment: Point #1 is not correct. `a.sort` is not invoking the `sort` method.  If called, it *would* mutate the `List`.

Comment: thank you for that, it's perfect solution but without a = a.sort(); --- a.sort(); is right

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `()` on `sort`. You can do

```dart
void main() {
  List a = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5];
  a.sort();
  print(a[a.length - 2]); //get second large item

  List b = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5];
  //or like revese sort
  b.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));
  print(b[1]);
  
}
```

Comment: i need to do this using a loop .

Comment: `sort()` method cant be use?

Comment: void main() {
  List a = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5];
  a.sort;
  int max = a[0];
  int second_last = a[0];
  for (int x in a) {
    if (x > max) {
      second_last = max;
      max = x;
    } else if (x > second_last && x != max) {
      second_last = x;
    }
  }
  print(second_last);
}

Comment: This solution is perfect

Comment: it is missing `a.sort()`, you can easily use lenght-2

Comment: "I need to do this using a loop" and now we see that this was a homework assignment, and you all just helped the OP cheat.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to print the second largest number on the list

1. Sort the array (desc).
2. Access the second element.

```dart
List a = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5];

a.sort((a, z) => z - a);
// final b = a.toList()..sort(...); if you do not want to modify the original array.

print(a.take(2));         // [13, 10]
print(a.take(2)[1]);      // [10]
print(a.take(2).skip(1)); // [10]
print(a.skip(1).first);   // [10]
```